# magento 2 cart, product array

Tags: magento2, product, configurable-product, cart

I want to manipulate the products showing in my mini cart.
I have configurable products, now i want to show only 1 parent configuration with color White if the customer has added Color white with size attribute M / L / XL.

[image: example]

So actually the code that im searching for would be where the array is created with the items to show.

Answer (score 0):

As per your current requirement you might need to override below class by creating a plugin and `doGetItemData` is the function which should be of your interest.

> Magento\Checkout\CustomerData\DefaultItem

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply.
This is only for each single item. I want to chagne the array where they are all in.
Is this possible with this function?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution:

In di.xml

```
<type name="Magento\Checkout\CustomerData\Cart">
    <plugin name="checkout.cart.message" type="{Vendor}\{Module}\Plugin\CustomerData\CartPlugin" sortOrder="1"/>
</type>
```

In {Module}\Plugin\CustomerData\CartPlugin.php

```
public function afterGetSectionData()
{
    $totals         = $this->getQuote()->getTotals();
    $subtotalAmount = $totals['subtotal']->getValue();

    return [
        'summary_count'             => $this->getSummaryCount(),
        'subtotalAmount'            => $subtotalAmount,
        'subtotal'                  => isset($totals['subtotal'])
            ? $this->checkoutHelper->formatPrice($subtotalAmount)
            : 0,
        'possible_onepage_checkout' => $this->isPossibleOnepageCheckout(),
        'items'                     => $this->getRecentItems(),
        'extra_actions'             => $this->layout->createBlock(\Magento\Catalog\Block\ShortcutButtons::class)
                                                    ->toHtml(),
        'isGuestCheckoutAllowed'    => $this->isGuestCheckoutAllowed(),
        'website_id'                => $this->getQuote()
                                            ->getStore()
                                            ->getWebsiteId(),
    ];
}
```

In this function items is getting called in $this->getRecentItems().
Now i can manipulate `protected function getRecentItems()` in my plugin class.